# Can I have multiple routes to the same remote LAN?

Tags: routing, openvpn, load-balancing

I am trying to connect two pfsense boxes with multiple `OpenVPN` tunnels. Currently, automatic route update makes only one route route active.

For example, I am connecting `192.168.10.0/24` and `192.168.33.0/24` LANs via `192.168.27.0/24` and `192.168.29.0/24` tuns and I have routes only via `27` network added.

What will happen if I add equivalent route via `29`? Will it work out of the box? Will it load balance?

Comment: If both routes have the same target network and same routing costs, load balancing should happen, otherwise the cheaper route has priority.

Comment: Is it working out of the box in Linux and FreeBSD?

Comment: As far as I know it should work out of the box on any OS which supports IP networking, so yes, Linux and FreeBSD should support this out of the box.

Comment: @roaima was a typo

Comment: I think Linux requires to define a single route with multipath settings (`man ip route` see `nexthop`) rather than automatically considering two routes looking equivalent as multipath routes.